# How to keep only some values in a column and plot them use Python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with 180000 rows and multiple columns. One column  includes names of forty different cities,"home_state". Only four cities are frequently appear and the others appear rarely .
When I plot with the following code, it doesn't look good because most of the cities have very few customers and I don't need them really to be on the plot.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
figure(num=None, figsize=(8,10), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='r')
sns.countplot(y = 'home_state', data = df)
plt.title('Total Number of Customers',size=18)
plt.ylabel('home_state',size=14)
plt.show()
```

So, my question is how can I only plot those four cities that are highly repeated?
Sorry for not being able to share the data.

Histogram of only four cities.

Comment: instead of data = df use filtered dataframe, for example data = df[df['city']=='Sample_city'] or df.isin([city_list])

Comment: @Samaneh Arzpeima -san, i think u need to subset data for four cities u wana plot.
You can refer it:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html

Comment: @ThuấnĐàoMinh tanx alot! right! df[df['home_state'].isin(['東京都', '神奈川県','埼玉県','千葉県'])] worked perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a lower limit so that only cities that have more than a set number of customers (eg. 10000) will be plotted.

```
plot_df = df[df.no_of_customers > 10000]
sns.countplot(y = 'home_state', data = data)
```

Comment: sorry @beh aaron , my question was wrong. sorry for wasting your time. I am going to edit it.